# What is NetrwBrowseX and what are the related vim mappings for?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I occasionally like to map vim keys to search and then do something.  I've been doing this for decades, but when I do it now, it takes over a second each time I use the mapped key.

I believe the cause is this, response from ":map" in vim:

```
n  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
n  <Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#NetrwBrowseX(expand("<cWORD>"),0)<CR>
```

What are these mappings for, and how can I get rid of them?

The map I'm adding today is

```
:map g nz.
```

Simply so every time I find the searched term, it's centered in the screen so I can quickly compare contexts.

Comment: This looks like a case of recursive vs non-recursive mapping. Could you show us an example of conflicting mapping?

Comment: edited and added, showing the obvious conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `nunmap gx`.

From the source code `netrw.vim`:

```
" s:NetrwBrowseX:  (implements "x") executes a special "viewer" script or program for the {{{2
"              given filename; typically this means given their extension.
"              0=local, 1=remote
fun! netrw#NetrwBrowseX(fname,remote)
```

Comment: Thanks -- actually that should have been obvious.

Comment: I see now that I can use "gn" to pop up an editor for the file whose name the cursor is on, from a directory listing in vim.